# javascript library conflict

Tags: jquery, javascript

I'm working with a project that uses scriptaculous. I want to add some extra features and I found a jquery plugin that can help me with that. So to use the jquery plugin, I have to add jquery, but the project has scriptaculous. I will add the code that calls the plugin as inline script and will link to jquery and the jquery plugin. Should I expect any conflicts? Is it really bad to have 2 libraries, and is it known to normally break the code. The plugin requires that I study it first before I know how to use it exactly, so I thought I'd ask before learning it the hard way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use both jquery.js and scriptaculous.js files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226866/use-both-jquery-js-and-scriptaculous-js-files)

Answer (score 1):

Enabling [no-conflict mode in jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries) should help with any problems that may arise, though problems are unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

It's not like it's never been done before. There's no reason for there to be any conflicts, ideally you can use both. However, you should consider if what was done in Scriptaculous can be done in jQuery so as to only have on lib.

Comment: I know it's been done before, but I remember hearing conflicts usually arise.